# SQL:UpdateText function :How to use?

Tags: sql

can anyone show me an example of using SQL server UPDATETEXT funciton.I want to apply some text replacement from one column(which is of type text) from one of my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Books Online:

```
USE pubs;
GO
ALTER DATABASE pubs SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DECLARE @ptrval binary(16);
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(pr_info) 
   FROM pub_info pr, publishers p
      WHERE p.pub_id = pr.pub_id 
      AND p.pub_name = 'New Moon Books'
UPDATETEXT pub_info.pr_info @ptrval 88 1 'b';
GO
ALTER DATABASE pubs SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

More info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReplaceTextColumn
(
  @TableName sysname,
  @ColumnName sysname,
  @PKColumnName sysname,
  @PKId bigint,
  @OldString nvarchar(max),
  @NewString nvarchar(max)
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = N'
DECLARE @ptrval binary(16);
DECLARE @insert_offset int;

SELECT 
  @ptrval = TEXTPTR('+ @ColumnName + ')
FROM ' + @TableName + '
WHERE
  ' + @PKColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@PKId as varchar(10)) + '

SELECT
  @insert_offset = PATINDEX(N''%' + @OldString + N'%'', '+ @ColumnName + ') - 1
FROM ' + @TableName + '
WHERE 
  ' + @PKColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@PKId as varchar(10)) + '

WHILE @insert_offset > -1
BEGIN
  UPDATETEXT '+ @TableName + '.'+ @ColumnName + ' @ptrval @insert_offset ' + CAST(LEN(@OldString) as varchar(5)) + ' ''' + @NewString + ''';

  SELECT 
    @insert_offset = PATINDEX(N''%' + @OldString + N'%'', '+ @ColumnName + ') - 1
  FROM ' + @TableName + '
  WHERE 
    ' + @PKColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@PKId as varchar(10)) + '
END
'

--print @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO
```

Here is an example showin the use the sql ReplaceTextColumn stored procedure in an.

```
EXEC ReplaceTextColumn N'TextData', N'txt', N'Id', 7, N'ĞüiŞçıÇÜş', N'T-SQL'
```

For more information you can read from here
[Example and SP](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/update-text-column-using-updatetext.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer should stand on its own with a link. Please put any relevant information in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a First timer.

Comment: No worries, I'm just here to give general advice. Now that you have done that I will give you an upvote to counter whoever gave you a downvote.